# qt qgraphicsitem disappear after minimize the window

Tags: qt, qgraphicsitem

Sorry it's quite hard to provide any source code, it's a huge project provided by others. But the problem's behavior is that the qgraphicsitem(some line segments) would disappear after the window is minimized and reopened. what could be the possible problem? please give some hint and suggestions.

Comment: Try replicating the issue in a small test project and if the error shows up, share the code of the test project.

Comment: That may be anything. My first thought is that this item is not being removed, it is just ignored by Qt painters because of too small ` boundingRect`. They can also do something explicitly on window minimization. Provide us more info, see if `QGraphicsItem` instance exist in the memory still and what scene is returned by its `scene()` method after restoration.